# Run application on local machine and show GUI on remote display (22.04)

Tags: xorg, 22.04, remote

This is duplicate of this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/203173/run-application-on-local-machine-and-show-gui-on-remote-display) but it needs an update for Ubuntu 22.04

So I needed to use x without ssh into a remote computer, but the answers in the question were for 12.xx.
I'm running Kubuntu 22.04 sddm.

The answers given do

- A:output this error `Error: Can't open display: 192.168.1.49:0`
- B:use ssh and don't work
- C:use a program that is not in the Ubuntu repo

Edit:
so i did grep -r 'nolisten tcp' /ect/ edit the file nano /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc to have -listen tcp in it and it still does not work note i am using sddm note i did this on the computer to have gui window displayed

Comment: Most of the answers seems still valid. Have you tried them all? List your problem with each answer in you question.

Comment: yes i wiil edit

Comment: *"So I needed to remove use x without ssh into a computer"* makes no sense. So you want to remove X? Or use it? Why don't you want to use ssh?

Comment: Wops wired spelling fix it

Comment: And ssh I have to install and on local network ssh should not be required

Comment: You may find this recent Unix & Linux thread helpful: [Xt error: Can't open display despite xhost and Xauthority configured](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/704290/xt-error-cant-open-display-despite-xhost-and-xauthority-configured/704298#704298)

Comment: so i did `grep -r 'nolisten tcp' /ect/` edit the file `nano /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc` to have `-listen tcp` in it and it still does not work note i am using sddm note i did this on the computer to have gui window displayed

Comment: @lnee Please update your question with the new information and then tag the person who asked for that information in the comments. like I have tagged you in this comment. The comments are mainly for us to ask for clarification and new information. As the person asking the question, you should always update the question.